# How to track where users have been? (database)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

For an event/game on a site I want to track every page a user goes to and store it by their username.  It needs to be done through a database so it's accessible and the data can be manipulated.  I've only ever used MySQL, so my solution where I'm at right now would just be a table of page visits with the username and the page that was visited.

This seems grossly inefficient for scaling purposes, though.  This sort of thing could end up with millions of rows in a matter of weeks or less.

Another example of something that just doesn't seem like it would be efficient is a voting system.  For example on stack overflow, every vote someone places would be another row to a table.  This just doesn't seem like the best way to store data.

What's the best alternative for these sorts of applications?
Thanks!

Comment: mysql is designed to hold vast amounts of data. So as long as your storage capacity can hold it, it won't be a problem

Comment: Even if a table has, say, 50 million rows?  I mean don't get me wrong, I'm not anticipating that, but I want to be prepared for it.

Comment: I guess it just seems like a database that stored the username only once and then held all the data related to that username somehow would be more efficient.  (I don't know if that exists, of course)

Comment: @user3011922 - I've used tables that have millions of rows. So long as you've got proper indexing set up, they're incredibly speedy. And you will need to normalize the database, too - store user information once, in one table, and just link that to the other tables, rather than duplicate the information everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What @Andrewsi said. As long as the db is properly constructed - ie at least 2nd but depending on the complexity of it, probably better to be 3rd normal form - It won't be a problem. That is what databases are for.

Do a bit of research into DB normalization, and proper indexing techniques and you'll be fine.

Comment: I see what look like some really informative books (one in particular being a textbook) on database practices.  Do you think that'll do the trick, or should I go for something specifically on MySQL?

Comment: If it talks about normalization, it should be fine, it's basically the same across DBs.

Answer (score 0):

If we use your first example - capturing analytics data - storing each page visit as a new row is the most flexible and useful format for the data.  You could simply store a row for each user and page combination and then increment a value every time a page visit occurs, but then you lose the ability to do things like filter/group data based on date/time.

MySQL can handle millions of rows without issue.  That's exactly what databases are for, after all.  You need to make sure that you use innodb tables and index the fields that you want to filter against.  You should also choose sensible data types, e.g. pick the smallest possible data type.

Querying millions of rows will not be "quick," but on the other hand that is not something you would ever let your users do, so it shouldn't affect their experience.

Comment: Ideally, the users do need to be able to query the table directly.  How else are they going to be able to see which pages they've been to, beyond a 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE username=:username' type query?

Answer (score 0):

Programming things this way is the standard method. It's what databases are used for. However, as your application grows, it will eventually reach the size where it becomes unmanageable and it's time to scale it, as you noted. (At least, assuming that it's as successful and as popular as you're implying it will be.)

At that point, it would be time to look into things like sharding, replica sets, or ElasticSearch. You may want to consider designing this using [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) rather than MySQL right now, because Mongo makes it fairly easy to set up shards and replica sets, and being JSON-based makes it highly-compatible with Elastic Search.

It all depends on how much further ahead you want to plan this, and whether you really believe the site's popularity is going to explode to that level.